# Player not moving when tapped

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have it set up so that my player should jump to wherever I tap on the screen, however, it won't budge. I triple checked my code and can't find anything wrong. Can someone please help?

Here is my code for my GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit

var player: Player!
var snowflake: Snowflake!
var isFingerOnPlayer = false
var gameOver = false
var playerTouched = false
var touching: Bool = false
var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil
let xPlayerForce: CGFloat = 30
let yPlayerForce: CGFloat = 40
var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
   player = Player()
    addChild(player)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    snowflake = Snowflake()
    addChild(snowflake)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        lastTouch = location
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    lastTouch = nil
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if let touch = lastTouch {
    var xForce: CGFloat = 0.0
    var yForce: CGFloat = 0.0
    let xTouchOffset = (touch.x - player.position.x)

    let yTouchOffset = (touch.y - player.position.y)

    if xTouchOffset > 0.0 
    {
        xForce = xPlayerForce
    } 
    else if xTouchOffset < 0.0
    {
        xForce = -xPlayerForce
    } // else we do nothing

    if yTouchOffset > 0.0 
    {
        yForce = yPlayerForce
    } // here you can choose whether you want it to push
    // the player node down, using similar code from the
    // above if statement

    let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: xForce, dy: yForce)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you are not really attempting to trigger the jump when tapping from the looks of it, rather when you are _moving_ your finger about.

Comment: Well, yes, but when I make that first tap, my player should jump, but its just not moving. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The first tap  `touchesBegan` does nothing. Your lastTouch property will only get a value as long as you move your finger about `touchesMoved`. The second you release it you are setting it to nil `touchesEnded`.

Comment: No matter what I do my player doesn't move. Not even if I move my finger (well mouse) everywhere.

Comment: OK. Does your sprite actually have a physicsbody? Does the `if let touch=` condition fire?

Comment: Yes, and its set up and called in a different .swift file. Im not sure what you mean by the  `if let touch =`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89390/discussion-between-nickfalk-and-rae-tucker).

Answer (score 0):

You are right by saying you don't NEED code in touches began, but from what you are saying you should probably. I would try just setting the location of the object in touches began and then updating it in touches moved.

Comment: Ill try this. What would updating it look like?

Comment: It would follow your movement. If you just want it moved once, just do the touches began part.